# Trying to set ImageView from Url with Bitmap

Tags: android, url, imageview, android-bitmap

I am trying to set my ImageView.I have the url of the image and trying to make it bitmap and after set this bitmap to my ImageView.However, Bitmap result, argument of onPostExecute, is coming as null from download_Image function. It means ' BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is); ' is returning null.

```
this.ImageView1 = (ImageView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.ImageView1);
ImageView1.setTag(URL);

new AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap>(){
 ImageView imageView = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
      final Bitmap[] b = new Bitmap[1];
      this.imageView = imageViews[0];

      activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          b[0] =download_Image((String) imageView.getTag());
        }
      });

    return b[0];

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    public Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

    //---------------------------------------------------

      URL newurl = null;

      try {
        newurl = new URL(url);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      Bitmap mIcon_val = null;

      try {
        URLConnection urlConnection=newurl.openConnection();
        InputStream is=urlConnection.getInputStream();
        mIcon_val=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

     return mIcon_val;

     //---------------------------------------------------

    }

}.execute(ImageView1);
```

How can I deal with that problem?

Comment: Just load the image from url through glide, why do you need it in bitmap?

Comment: There are many [image loading libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46). Use one.

Comment: Just use Glide or picasso what is your need. If you want bitmap you can download file directly using asynchttp jar.After downloading the file you can convert to bitmap easily

Comment: Wait are you downloading in your runOnUiThread ? Then what is the point of your AsyncTask ? You're probably getting null because downloading in UI thread results in exception so mIcon_val stays null.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have solved the problem with deleting UI thread. @Damien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this code and comment if any problem**`public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ImageView imageView;
private String imageUrl ="image url";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);

    new AsyncTask<ImageView, Void, Bitmap>(){
        ImageView imageView = null;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {
            final Bitmap[] b = new Bitmap[1];
            this.imageView = imageViews[0];

                    b[0] =download_Image(imageUrl);

           return b[0];

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }

        public Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

            //---------------------------------------------------

            URL newurl = null;

            try {
                newurl = new URL(url);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bitmap mIcon_val = null;

            try {
                URLConnection urlConnection=newurl.openConnection();
                InputStream is=urlConnection.getInputStream();
                mIcon_val= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return mIcon_val;

            //---------------------------------------------------

        }

    }.execute(imageView);}}`
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

In your activtiy

```
Glide.with(activity.this).load(your image url).into(imageView);
```

Comment: I implemented your solution but still there is no image. Image view that I want to set image belogs a view which is infoWindow ( `infoWindow = (ViewGroup)getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_marker_window, null);` ). Does it cause any problem to use glide?

Comment: then use getActitviy() instead of activtiy.this. And if you are still getting the issue then try to load a static image into the imageView for first if it is also not showing then there is some problem with your view.

Comment: I have already implemented what you said.Still no image `Glide.with(getActivity()).load(URL).into(ImageView1);`

Comment: check my edited answer, try to show ic_launcher in the image, if it is still not showing that as well then there is problem in your view